# Prove that if $n,m \in \mathbb{N}^{\gt0}$ and $nm$ is even then either $n$ is even or $m$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Q: Prove that if $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $nm$ is even then either $n$ is even or $m$ is even.

Attempt Contrapositive: Assume $n$ and $m$ are odd. Then $n=2k-1$ and $m=2k'-1$ and

$nm=(2k-1)(2k'-1)=2(2kk'-k-k'+1)-1$

how do I show that $2kk'-k-k'+1 \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Attempt: since $k,k' \in \mathbb{N}$ $k \geq1$ and $k' \geq1$

Thus $2kk'\geq 2$ and $2kk'-k-k'+1>0$

Comment: Good approach.  It is clear, is it not?, that $2kk'-k-k'\in \mathbb Z$.  If it were $≤0$ then $nm<0$ which contradicts the fact that $nm$ is, clearly, a natural number.

Comment: @lulu sorry I messed up it should be 2kk'-k-k'+1

Comment: Well... $m=(2k-1)(2k'-1)=4kk'-2k-2k'+1=2(kk'-k-k')+1$ and if $kk'-k-k'$ were negative then $mn<1$.

Comment: Why do you want to show that $2kk'-k-k'+1\in\Bbb N$? You rather want to show that it is $\notin 2\Bbb N$

Comment: Another approach, if you have it available, is to use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic: The prime $2$ appears in the prime factorization of $nm$, therefore etc.

Comment: If $2|nm$ then $2|n$ or $2|m$ because $2$ is prime

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's easier to use $n = 2k + 1$ and $m = 2k' + 1$ where $k,k' \ge 0$. Then $nm = (2k + 1)(2k' + 1) = 4kk' + 2k + 2k' + 1 = 2(2kk' + k + k') + 1 \gt 0$ since the part multiplying $2$ is $\ge 0$ and $1$ is being added. Also, as it has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $2$, it's odd.

Answer (score 1):

$2kk'-k-k'+1$

$=(kk'-k)+(kk'-k')+1$

$=k(k'-1)+k'(k-1)+1$

As $k$ and $k'$ are natural numbers, $k-1\ge0$ and $k'-1\ge0$, so $k(k'-1)$ and $k'(k-1)$ are nonnegative integers. The "$+1$" will make the number from nonnegative integer to natural number.

$\therefore2kk'-k-k'+1 \in \mathbb{N} .$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using your approach, consider $n, m$ odd where $n = 2k + 1$ and $m = 2k' + 1$, $k, k' \geq 0$

Comment: the problem is this problem is restricted to natural numbers so 1 is not defined if n=2k+1

Comment: If this were integers I would say 2kk'+k+k' is in $\mathbb{Z}$ since Z is closed under addition and multiplication

Comment: I'm considering that zero is a natural number

Comment: The book im using says it will not consider 0 natural

Comment: Ok, there are these types of approach

Comment: @Eastcoastdancer What about $k=0$? $k$ doesn't necessarily have to be a natural number, as long as $n,m$ are natural.

Comment: @Peter Foreman I don't think that is the correct approach for the book Im using since after each example the author says "Now we need to make sure the subtraction is legal" and I probably should have stated k is a natural number

Comment: @Eastcoastdancer I really understand that you want to consider the problem in $\mathbb{N}$, but in this case you can't use the operation subtraction

Comment: The author defines a "subtraction" within the natural numbers as if m,n are natural and m>n, there exists a unique natural number s such that m=n+s

Comment: Ok, in this case I think that the answer given by @Culver Kwan is more usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

A number $s \in \Bbb N = \{1,2,\dots\}$ is even iff it can be written as $s= 2k$.

A number $s \in \Bbb N$ is odd iff $s = 1$ or it can be written as $s= 2k + 1$.

Suppose both $m$ and $n$ are odd.

Case 1: $m = 1$ and $n = 1$. Then $mn=1$ is odd.

Case 2: $m = 1$ and $n = 2k +1$. Then $mn = 2k + 1$ is odd.

Case 3: $m = 2k+1$ and $n = 1$. Then $mn = 2k + 1$ is odd.

Case 4: $m = 2k+1$ and $n = 2k'+1$ . Then

$$mn = 4kk'+2k + 2k'+1 =2(2kk'+k+k')+1$$
is odd.

So the product of any two odd numbers is odd.